# ComboBox2 get fields in function of ComboBox1

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I have to select one brand of moto. If i select "KTM", i want to get Ktm's motos. If i select "HVA", i want HVA's motos. Etc ..

I have a List of models with all models, and in function what i select, i want to add models by this brand and return this in my ComboBox2.

Modele.cs :

class Modele

```
 {
        public string NomModele;

    public static List<Modele> lesModeles = new List<Modele>() {

        // Husqvarna
        new Modele() { NomModele = "TE"},
        new Modele() { NomModele = "FE"},

        // KTM
        new Modele() { NomModele = "EXC"},
        new Modele() { NomModele = "EXC-F"}
    };

    public Modele() { }

    public Modele(string NomModele)
    {
        this.NomModele = NomModele;
    }
}
```

Main.cs :

```
namespace SuiviEntretien
{
    public partial class SuiviEntretien : Form
    {
        public SuiviEntretien()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        this.lesMarques.Items.AddRange(Marque.lesMarques.Select(x => x.NomMarque).ToArray());
        this.lesModeles.Items.AddRange(Modele.lesModeles.Select(x => x.NomModele).ToArray());
    }

    private void SuiviEntretien_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SauvegarderMoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Moto maMoto = new Moto(
                maMarque.Text = lesMarques.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                monModele.Text = lesModeles.SelectedItem.ToString()
                );
            MessageBox.Show("Moto enregistrée avec succès !", "Information");
            tabControl1.SelectTab(MaMoto);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Il manque des informations !", "Information");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for further help.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer has been made with some assumptions, those being:

-You have a ComboBox that contains values, when a value is selected another ComboBox needs to re-populate itself with a new list of data.

Depending on the scale of this problem I would recommend two solutions. Move your data into a relational database and access it accordingly, then populate your first ComboBox as a list of all main keys. (One to many methodology) then populate your second ComboBox according to the first ComboBox value.

Assuming you want to build your list dynamically and want to avoid a database then simply use functionality based on if the ComboBox changes.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
if (ComboBox1.Text == "KTM")
{
    // Populate ComboBox2 with KTM data.
} 
else
{
   // Populate ComboBox2 with some other data.    
}
}
```

This should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for help. It's working nice. But it's not possible to write a function to call this code rather than writing in Main ?